# How to set the background color of a label in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, background, label

I have a label but setting the Background property not seem to do anything:

```
    <Label Content="{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource LocStrings}}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Name="label2"  Background="Blue" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

This does not show a blue background (while the property Background is recognized.

Also when using the Label.Background 'way' I do not see a blue background.

Update:

I used the following minimalistic code:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   Title="TEST" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="TEXT TO TEST" Foreground="Green" Background="Orange"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What I see is the tekst in green but without any orange background.

Comment: Weird. It should. Do you see any binding errors in the output window? That shouldn't matter but worth checking.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange No I don't get a binding error.

Comment: I put a StackPanel around it with a background color, that seems to work well.

Comment: Just tested by removing the binding, it works. You need to post sample program which reproduces the issue.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers You shouldn't need to have a `StackPanel` to set the background. Is the label floating on top of other elements? How are adjacent controls arranged?

Comment: seems like you want to display a string value so perhaps use TextBlock instead of Label. Content model of Label may not be required in this scenario.

Comment: @pushpraj: A TextBlock works as expected (with orange background). If you make it an answer I can set it to 'accepted'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are binding to a string value so using a `TextBlock` instead of `Label` is worth here. A content model of Label may not be required in this scenario.

here is an example

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource LocStrings}}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4" Name="label2"  Background="Blue" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

some other benefits of displaying text in a TextBlock instead of a Label

Unlike a Label a Textblock is derived directly from FrameworkElement instead of deriving from a Control thus making it lightweight.

A Label follows content model so the appearance may get affected by the content and its type and / or any style or template defined for the same.

read here for more [Differences between Label and TextBlock](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/)

Comment: Thanks, this solution works perfectly for me (also thanks for the extra link with differences).

Answer (score 3):

```
<Label Content="{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource LocStrings}}"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4" Name="label2"  Background="Blue" 
      VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Have you tried to just enter some text in the Content and checked the **binding output**, maybe there is something wrong with your binding. Because it works just fine here.
Note that I set **HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"** instead of left, which will make the label use all the horizontal avaliable space. If you don't have anything bound your label will be invisible in your case above, you may use this in combination with the output to figure out what's likely wrong with your binding as stated by others, like  Sriram Sakthivel and PoweredByOrange. For helping you with that, we need a bit more information :)

Hope it helps,

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: I edited my example, but still does not seems to work. The HorizontalAlignment addition does not make any difference either.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers         <Grid>
            <Label Content="blablablbalbalbal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4" Name="label2"  Background="Blue" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
         </Grid> Stretches horizontally just fine here, with the default font size. If you for some reason want it over the entire screen add VerticalAlignment="Stretch" aswell. The H..ContentAlignment and V..ContentAlignment tells how the content (text) should behave within the label control. The Label control has some more features than TextBlock suggested above, I mostly use TextBlocks my self as I must admit to.

Comment: I meant that the Horizontal/VerticalAlignment is working ok, but does not make any differ for the background color. But I (already) voted your answer +1 because it might be useful for others.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Sorry I really don't know then, it's working here. Strange.

Comment: no problem at all ... the other solution worked... thanks for the answer and thinking with me.